# All the elements of the matrix $A + A^2 + A^3 + A^4 + A^5$ are non zero.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If a graph with $10$ vertices has $5$ distinct eigenvalues, then all the elements of the matrix $$A + A^2 + A^3 + A^4 + A^5$$ are non zero.

We have to verify if the statement is True or False.

Here $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph.

---

I am not getting any clue how to approach the problem. Any hints will be useful.

Comment: What does $A$ have to do with the graph?

Comment: A is the adjacency matrix

Comment: Hint: Since it is adjacency matrix, what does each entry of $A+A^2+A^3+A^4+A^5$ counts for? The graph has $10$ vertices, we can have that if some of the entries are zero, if and only if the graph is disconnected. Now your work be: construct a disconnected graph with $5$ distinct eigenvalues, or prove that if the graph is disconnected, the number of distinct eigenvalues will be not $5$?

Answer (score 2):

It is false.

Note that for each $u,v$, the $uv$-th entry of $A+A^2+A^3+A^4+A^5$ counts the number of walks in the underlying graph $G$ from $u$ to $v$ with $1,2,3,4$, or $5$ edges. So this is nonzero for each $u,v$ only if [but not necessarily if] the underlying graph $G$ is connected i.e., if every $u$ and $v$ are even reachable from each other in $G$.

In fact however we can construct a graph $G$ on $10$ vertices where both the adjavency matrix $A$ has precisely $5$ distinct eigenvalues, and also that $G$ is disconnected. Let one component of $G$ be a cycle on $4$ vertices, and let each of the remaining $6$ vertices each be in a matching with another vertex [so $3$ additional edges]. Then the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ are $2,0,-2$ [from the $4$-cycle] and $1,-1$ [from the matching w $3$ edges on the $6$ remaining vertices]. Furthermore, the eigenvalue $0$ has multiplicity two, and the eigenvalues $1,-1$ have multiplicity three each.

So as $A$ as in the previous paragraph has $5$ distinct eigenvalues but the underlying graph $G$ is disconnected, it follows from earlier that there is a $u,v$ such that the $uv$-th component of $A+A^2+A^3+A^4+A^5$ is $0$. So indeed, the statement as in the OP is false.

Comment: *"So this is nonzero for each , only if [but not necessarily if] the underlying graph  is connected"* -- note it is actually an **iff** in this case; a real symmetric matrix with 5 distinct eigenvalues tells you the minimal polynomial is degree 5

Comment: It may be true that connectedness $+ 5$ distinct eigenvalues implies $G$ has diameter $5$ or less [think of $5$ as the largest power of the adj matrix $A$ of $G$, not as the number of distinct eigenvalues] ***together*** gives all entries of $A+A^2+A^3+A^4+A^5$ nonzero. But I'm not seeing how the above comment establishes that, and you do need both conditions. The answer below shows $5$ distinct eigenvalues does not suffice. But neither does connectedness in and of itself; indeed take $G$ to be a path on $10$ vtcs.

Comment: *"But I'm not seeing how the above comment establishes that"* -- again, it is because $A$ has a *minimal polynomial* of degree 5; I take for granted that $A$ is real non-negative.  I.e. $\mathbf e_i^T A^k\mathbf e_j= 0$ for $k\in\big\{1,2,3,4,5\big\}$ for some $i,j$ implies there is no path from i to j since all positive integer powers of $A$ can be written as a linear combination of its first 5 powers.  (This logic of course works any time you have a minimal polynomial degree $\leq 5$.)

Comment: for avoidance of doubt: that was meant to read as $\mathbf e_i^T A^k\mathbf e_j= 0$ for *all* $k\in\big\{1,2,3,4,5\big\}$